# Using RegEx to identify emails from Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, list, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner working on a program that can scrape emails from a given website. The code is as follows:

```
import requests, bs4, re
print('Fetching Website...')
res = requests.get('https://examplewebsite.com')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
type(soup)

my_list = []
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    my_list.append(link.get('href'))

emailregex = re.compile(r'''(
    [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-:]+
    @
    [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+
    \.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
    )''', re.VERBOSE)

newlist = list(filter(emailregex.search, my_list))
print(newlist)

print('---Done---')
```

When I run the code, however, I get an error: "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object". I found that if I do:

```
newlist = list(filter(emailregex.search, str(my_list)))
print(newlist)
```

The error will go away, but my "newlist" doesn't contain any results. I have verified that "my_list" does return a list of expected results. I found that if I print "my_list" and paste its contents into a new file where I add it to a list run the same code, it works just fine, so I don't believe its an issue with the Regex. I think it might be something with the data-type in "my_list"? I don't really have any good ideas, so any help at all would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: are you really `extracting` `emails` from `anchor` tags?

Comment: Your regex for email is really poor, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Yes, the code extracts emails formatted as 'mailto:jdoe@gmail.com' (at least for the specific website I have been looking at). I have only been learning for a couple weeks, so I am sure there are much better ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @toto Thank you for your help. I just started learning so I'm sure there is a lot of room for  improvement. I will check out your links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"` is because `my_list` is not including only string, however `str(my_list)` is going to convert the variable into a big string

```
print(str(my_list)) # this is a string
print(type(str(my_list)))  # output: str
```

You need to change every item of `my_list` to string and then try again

```
my_list = list(map(str, my_list))
newlist = list(filter(emailregex.search, my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = "".join([item.get("href")
                      for item in soup.findAll("a", href=True)])
    matches = re.findall(
        r'''[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-:]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}''', re.VERBOSE, target)
    for match in matches:
        print(match)


main("https://www.example.com")
```